# Failure: UsersSignupTest#test_valid_signup_information_with_account_activation Expected: 1 Actual: 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following railstutorial and am having this error in chapter 10.
I thought it should be similar with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27395083/user-signup-test-failing-in-m-hartls-rails-tutorial). Unfortunately, the solution does not work with my problem.

Changing `1` into `2` in line `assert_equal 1, ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size` in user_signup_test.rb make the test GREEN. lol.
But I am a complete noob so do not really understand the real issue.

could someone show me where I miss?

```
Failure:
UsersSignupTest#test_valid_signup_information_with_account_activation 
[/home/xxx/sample_app/test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:30]:
Expected: 1 
Actual: 2
```

user_signup_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersSignupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  # test "the truth" do
  #   assert true
  # end
def setup
  ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear
end

test "invalid signup information" do
    get signup_path
    assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
      post users_path, user: { name:  "",
                               email: "user@invalid",
                               password:              "foo",
                               password_confirmation: "bar" }
    end
    assert_template 'users/new'
  end

  test "valid signup information with account activation" do
    get signup_path
    assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
      post users_path, user: { name:  "Example User",
                               email: "user@example.com",
                               password:              "password",
                               password_confirmation: "password" }
    end
    assert_equal 1, ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size
    user = assigns(:user)
    assert_not user.activated?
    # Try to log in before activation.
    log_in_as(user)
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    # Invalid activation token
    get edit_account_activation_path("invalid token")
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    # Valid token, wrong email
    get edit_account_activation_path(user.activation_token, email: 'wrong')
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    # Valid activation token
    get edit_account_activation_path(user.activation_token, email: user.email)
    assert user.reload.activated?
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert is_logged_in?
  end
    #assert_template 'users/show'
    #assert is_logged_in?

end
```

user_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update, :index, :destroy ]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def index
    #@users = User.all
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    #debugger
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)    # Not the final implementation!
    if @user.save
      # Handle a successful save.
      #log_in @user
      #flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      #redirect_to @user
      @user.send_activation_email
      UserMailer.account_activation(@user).deliver_now
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url

    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      #Handle a successful update
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User deleted"
    redirect_to users_url
  end

private
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end

# Before filters

# Confirms a logged-in user.
def logged_in_user
  unless logged_in?
    store_location
    flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
    redirect_to login_url
  end
end

# Confirms the correct user.
def correct_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  #redirect_to root_url unless @user == current_user
  redirect_to root_url unless current_user?(@user)
end

# Confirms an admin user.
def admin_user
  redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
end

end
```

user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer

  # Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
  # with the following lookup:
  #
  #   en.user_mailer.account_activation.subject
  #
  def account_activation(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: user.email, subject: "Account activation"
  end

  # Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
  # with the following lookup:
  #
  #   en.user_mailer.password_reset.subject
  #
  def password_reset
    @greeting = "Hi"

    mail to: "to@example.org"
  end
end
```

application_mailer.rb

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  #default from: "from@example.com"
  default from: "noreply@example.com"
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

account_activation_controller.eb

```
class AccountActivationsController < ApplicationController

  def edit
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    if user && !user.activated? && user.authenticated?(:activation, params[:id])
      user.activate
      log_in user
      flash[:success] = "Account activated!"
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Invalid activation link"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
end
```

session_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        if user.activated?
        log_in user
        params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
          #redirect_to user
        redirect_back_or(user)
      else
        message = "Account not activated."
        message += "Check your email for the activation link."
        flash[:warning] = message
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    else
    flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination' # Not quite right!
    render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    log_out if logged_in?
    log_out
    redirect_to root_url
  end

end
```

user_mailer_test.rb

require 'test_helper'

```
class UserMailerTest < ActionMailer::TestCase
  test "account_activation" do
    user = users(:michael)
    user.activation_token = User.new_token
    mail = UserMailer.account_activation(user)
    assert_equal "Account activation", mail.subject
    assert_equal [user.email], mail.to
    assert_equal ["noreply@example.com"], mail.from
    assert_match user.name,               mail.body.encoded
    assert_match user.activation_token,   mail.body.encoded
    assert_match CGI::escape(user.email), mail.body.encoded
  end

  test "password_reset" do
    mail = UserMailer.password_reset
    assert_equal "Password reset", mail.subject
    assert_equal ["to@example.org"], mail.to
    assert_equal ["noreply@example.com"], mail.from
    assert_match "Hi", mail.body.encoded
  end

end
```

Comment: Without seeing your code that actually creates the user and sends the email, we have no way of knowing what the problem is.

Comment: ooops..sorry. I added some controllers to my post. would you like to take a look once again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@user.send_activation_email
UserMailer.account_activation(@user).deliver_now
```

Without seeing the rest of your code, this looks like it should send two separate emails. The second line definitely does send an email, but we can't see the User model to know what the first line is doing.

If that code does send two emails, then the test is failing correctly.

Comment: You are correct!

'UserMailer.account_activation(@user).deliver_now'

is refactored into

'send_activation_email' in user.rb

Comment: You are correct!

`UserMailer.account_activation(@user).deliver_now`

is refactored into

`send_activation_email` in user.rb